# RTL: how to test the html content of the whole component

Tags: react-testing-library, testing-library

I have a component which renders some conditional text on the basis of a prop. i want to test the rendered text. I can do that by getting a reference to the container from render and then chekcing container to have or not have a particular text content

```
const { container } = render(...);
expect(container).toHaveTextContent(...);
```

But, as the current suggestion is to use screen instead of render, which is more convenient to use generally, i am trying to figure out if this is possible with screen.

is there a way to have this test with screen instead of container?

I can may be use a test-id on the container div of my component and target that using `screen.getByTestId`, but that looksike overkill

Answer (score 0):

If the text you are looking for is inside an accessible element, such as a text field, button, etc, then it's always best to use one of the specific queries: `getByRole`, `getByLabelText`, etc, to find the text and assert on it. That would be very easy to test, e.g. `screen.getByRole('button').toHaveText(`.

Alternatively, if you cannot narrow the query down using one of the aforementioned queries, then you can do `expect(screen.getByText(/your text content/i)).toHaveTextContent(...)`;

This works well, but if the text isn't unique, it *can* be difficult to find elements, so you may need to go back to lean on: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-within/ (see React tab) or finally a test-id.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an expectation in your component using screen like this:

```js
expect(screen.getByRole("button").textContent).toMatchInlineSnapshot();
```

This will fill up the brackets of `toMatchInlineSnapshot()` with whatever the text content it received based on whatever your props are like this:

```js
toMatchInlineSnapshot(`"expected text content"`)`
```

If you are targeting whole container, you will have to then use `container` query like so:

```js
const { container } = render(...);
expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot()
```

and then run test, which will then fill brackets of `toMatchInlineSnapshot()` with the HTML like so:

```js
expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
  <div>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
`)
```

For more, refer here: [Snapshot Testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing)

For better queries, you can try using [Testing-Playground Chrome Extension](https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing)